# Highcharts is not displaying in the div at all, resulting in a blank page - Using python flask and jinja template?

Tags: jquery, python, highcharts, flask

Here is my index.html file. I have included the scripts in the correct order. I try to load the div with the dummy graph. I have tried including the scripts in base.html but nothing works. I had the scripts locally, I tried loading it from the CDN. Is CSRF_Enabled= False in flask an issue?  I have tried document.ready() event ... THe same code works fine in js fiddle .. I mean the graph part.

```
<!-- extend from base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!--- PAGE BLOCK 1 HAS QUERY AND CHART DIV -->
{% block page_content1 %}

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!--- JAVASCRIPT PART -->
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).on('load','#helloScript',function(){

    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});

</script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script id="helloScript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


{%  endblock %}
```

---

### base.html - Just in case

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/half_div.css') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">

<!--
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/rickshaw.min.css') }}">

<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.layout.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/rickshaw.min.js') }}'></script>
-->
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}My Dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container" id="main_container" style="border:1px solid black;">
    {% block page_content1 %}
    {% endblock %}

</div>

<div class="container" id="graph_container" style="border:1px solid black;">
    {% block page_content2 %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you please include the error you're getting?

Comment: Thats the problem.. I don`t see any error in the browser`s console. I tried setting breakpoints and it all looks fine. How else can I debug it?

Comment: It's strange, you should have errors in JS console, at least from Highcharts- you are including Highstock library twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the following changes to base.html works i.e. 
1. I included jquery.min.js manually before extending bootstrap/base.html so that the jquery gets loaded for sure. [ VIMP ]
2. Overridden the scripts and the styles block of bootstrap/base.html to include the scripts/stylesheets I want.

```
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}'></script>

{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/half_div.css') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
{% endblock %}


<!--
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/rickshaw.min.css') }}">
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.layout.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/rickshaw.min.js') }}'></script>
-->

{% block scripts %}
{{super()}}
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script id="helloScript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't including a lot of your JavaScript. All of these tags exist outside of any `block`.

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/half_div.css') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">

<!--
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/rickshaw.min.css') }}">

<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.layout.js') }}'></script>
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/rickshaw.min.js') }}'></script>
-->
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}'></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

They need to go inside a `block` that's overridden from the parent template, `bootstrap.html`. Ideally you'll place the stylesheets in `<head>` and the JavaScript in `<body>`.

```
<!-- base.html -->
{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}

    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/half_div.css') }}">
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/rickshaw.min.css') }}">

    <!-- this can stay here or go elsewhere (e.g., block metas) -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}

    <script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.min.js') }}'></script>
    <script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/d3.layout.js') }}'></script>
    <script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/rickshaw.min.js') }}'></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

If you use JavaScript on your page that relies on other libraries (e.g., jQuery), you'll want to make sure the library is loaded before your script. The easiest (and probably best) way to do this is include your script inside the `scripts` block.

```
<!-- some_other_template.html -->
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('load','#helloScript',function(){

        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ya. I just figured it out. It was bootstrap/base.html which was loading jquery.min.js which was overriding my inclusion of jquery.min.js and hence was getting loaded after highstock and exporting. Can you help more with your suggestion how I can avoid/override the jquery loaded by bootstrap.html?  Like here they show how to load custom js before boostrap loads its js .. but that won`t solve the issue. https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/docs/basic-usage.rst

Comment: I tried the approach on the link using super(). It included the js files in the body tag but I think they are getting loaded after the dom gets loaded so I get errors like $ is not defined and I was using $document.ready() to load my div, also tried on load still the same error?

Comment: I added some examples to help set up your templates.